# Angular + Leaflet: Map Container is already initialized when switching to another route component that use the same map

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm a beginner with regards to Leaflet and I'm having this problem.
In my project I have two route pages that dynamically use the Map component.
The Map component is reusable and receives as input the "data" and "type" properties, which affect the way the layers of the regions will be displayed on the map.

First route-page template:

```
<div class="progetto-italiae-page">
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-sidebar [navItems]="navItems"></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <app-numbers-summary></app-numbers-summary>
  <app-map [data]="data" [type]="dataType"></app-map>
</div>
```

Second route-page template:

```
<div class="linee-di-intervento-page">
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-sidebar [navItems]="navItems"></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <app-map [data]="data" [type]="dataType"></app-map>
</div>
```

This is the logic of the map component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() type: string = '';

  private map: Map | undefined;
  private regions!: any;

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = new Map('map', {
      center: [41.552, 12.574],
      zoom: 5,
      zoomControl: false,
    });

    new Control.Zoom({
      position: 'topright',
    }).addTo(this.map);

    const layer = new TileLayer(
      'http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 3,
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      }
    );

    this.map.addLayer(layer);
  }

  private initRegionsLayer() {
    const layer = new GeoJSON(this.regions, {
      style: (feature) =>
        this.styleService.regionsStyleMaker(feature, this.data, this.type),
    });

    this.map?.addLayer(layer);
  }

  constructor(
    private shapeService: MapShapesService,
    private styleService: MapShapesStyleService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    this.shapeService.getRegionsShapes().subscribe((regions) => {
      this.regions = regions;
      this.initRegionsLayer();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.map != null) {
      this.map.remove();
      this.map = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

Removing the map in ngOnDestroy the error no longer occurs in the console, but now I have another problem:

the first route that renders the map loads it correctly:
[image]

if, on the other hand, I switch to the second route that has to render the map, an empty container is displayed:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution as was having exact same problem!

The problem is in how the map is created.

Try like this:

Map component HTML:

```
<div #mapContainer></div>
```

Map component TS:

```
@ViewChild('mapContainer') private mapContainer: ElementRef;
private map: any;
```

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.map = L.map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, {
      center: [41.552, 12.574],
      zoom: 5,
      zoomControl: false
   });
}
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! This should be the approved answer.